# Change Out of Stock product overlay type on shop in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to change the Out of Stock notice which overlays the product images in my shop page in Woocommerce. I want it to say 'New stock coming soon' as I have done on the product page itself.
[image]
I have now discovered where to change it - in Flatsome theme: content_product.php and changed it as below:

```html
<div class="image-tools <?php echo flatsome_product_box_actions_class(); ?>">
<?php do_action( 'flatsome_product_box_actions' ); ?>
</div>
<?php if ( $out_of_stock ) { ?><div class="out-of-stock-label"><?php _e( 'New stock coming soon', 'woocommerce' ); ?></div><?php } ?>
</div>
```

and it works.

But this is in the parent theme. How do I change to an add_filter script so I can add to my child functions.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by translating the string and following this: https://businessbloomer.com/translate-single-string-woocommerce-wordpress/

I changed 'Sale!' to 'Out of Stock' (which is what originally appeared on my page) and changed 'On Offer' to 'New stock coming soon'.

Now the badge on my product images shows New stock coming soon instead of Out of Stock.